# Using expect, spawn with scp

Tags: shell, expect, scp, spawn

I'm currently trying to automate a file transfer using the scp command with a shell script and the expect package. Based on what I've seen it seems that I should have 
    `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`
But when I did that I still get the errors:

```
DirectoryChange.sh: line 33: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "*Password:*": no such file or directory
DirectoryChange.sh: line 35: send: command not found
DirectoryChange.sh: line 36: interact: command not found
```

The code I have works something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

repository=$PWD"/subdirectory/"
set pass "***********"

cd $repository
spawn scp -r user@host:/copyDirectory/ .
expect "*Password:*"
send "${pass}\r";
interact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're invoking your expect script like `sh DirectoryChange.sh`. Clearly `sh` is not the correct interpreter for an **expect** script.

- change the file extension: ".sh" is for shell scripts
- make sure it has execute permissions then launch it with `./DirectoryChange.exp`
- `repository=$PWD"/subdirectory/"` is not how to assign variables in expect. remove this line and edit the `cd` line to `cd subdirectory`
- you don't have to interact with scp, so change the last line to `expect eof`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to store passwords in scripts or any other file. Use SSH authentication keys instead.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/).